# How to compile YCSB for Hbase 0.96.0?

Tags: hbase, ycsb

I was stuck with the compilation issue of YCSB for Hbase 0.96.0. After I changed the pom.xml in YCSB/Hbase directory to

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
  <artifactId>hbase</artifactId>
  <version>0.96.0-hadoop2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
  <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

And try to run the command: mvn clean package in YCSB directory, it gives me a compilation error:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project hbase-binding: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.yahoo.ycsb:hbase-binding:jar:0.1.4: Failure to find org.apache.hbase:hbase:jar:0.96.0-hadoop2 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

Then I run mvn clean package -U to force updating the local repo, it gives me the same error...

Any help will be welcome! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try using hbase-client instead of hbase

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
  <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
  <version>0.96.0-hadoop2</version>
</dependency>
```

Also if you are using hadoop 1.1.2, you should use 0.96.0-hadoop1. 0.96.0-hadoop2 is for hadoop 2.*